# I am getting an error while pushing code to scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx

Good day all,
[image]
I am getting an error while pushing code to scratch org. Can someone help me, please?
ERROR running force:  *Unexpected argument: :source: push See more help with --help*

Comment: Hey, don't leave a blank space between "force" and ":source:push".

Comment: It is solved Thank you.....

Comment: @FelixvanHove add this as an answer so we can mark this as answered.

Comment: @PhilW Are you sure you want to mark this as answered? Not sure, if this is worthwhile.

Comment: Well, it's either that or delete the question?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no space between "force" and ":source:push" :-) Documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm).